# How do you solve $3^{x-1}$ = $2^x$ using natural logs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My pre-calc book wants me to solve $3^{x-1} = 2^x$ using natural logs. I 
 get (x-1)ln(3) = xln(2).  But from there I don't know where to go.  The book answer is $\frac{ln(3)}{ln(3) - ln(2)}$ can someone please expain to me the steps to get there?

Comment: "*I get $(x-1)\ln(3) = x\ln(2)$.*"  That is a great first step.  Now... from there, just remember that $\ln(3)$ is just a real number like any other.  You should know how to continue I hope if it were $(x-1)\times \color{red}{5} = x\times \color{red}{7}$ instead, right?  Don't be scared of the fact that these are logs rather than integers, they still behave in much the same way.  They just take a few more strokes of a pen to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just isolate $x$ to get $x\ln3 - \ln3 = x\ln 2 \implies x(\ln3 - \ln 2) = \ln 3$

> $$x  =\frac{\ln 3}{\ln3 -\ln2}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**$$3^{x-1}=2^x\iff\left(\frac32\right)^x=3$$

Comment: Hi José, I think there was a small mistake in the expression which I corrected. Cheers

Comment: Thank you. You were right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

$$x \ln 3 -\ln 3 = x\ln 2$$

so if we swap $x\ln2 $ and $\ln 3$ we get $$x \ln 3 -x\ln 2 = \ln 3$$

so $$x (\ln 3 -\ln 2) = \ln 3$$

so $$x = {\ln 3\over \ln 3 -\ln 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$x\ln(3)-\ln(3)=x\ln(2) \implies x(\ln(3)-\ln(2))=\ln(3)$ hence $x=\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(3)-\ln(2)}$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-1)\ln3=x\ln 2$$
$$x(\ln 3-\ln 2)=\ln 3$$
$$x=\frac {\ln 3}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$$